# Why is the default case in my switch statement executing unexpectedly in my grade-counting program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int grade;
    int aCount = 0;
    int bCount = 0;
    int cCount = 0;
    int dCount = 0;
    int fCount = 0;

    printf("Enter grades\n");
    printf("Enter the EOF to end input\n");

    while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF ){
        switch (grade){
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                ++aCount;
                break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                ++bCount;
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                ++cCount;
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                ++dCount;
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                ++fCount;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid\n");
                printf("Enter a new grade\n");
                break;      
    }
}
    printf("\nTotals for each letter are:\n");
    printf("A: %d\n", aCount);
    printf("B: %d\n", bCount);
    printf("C: %d\n", cCount);
    printf("D: %d\n", dCount);
    printf("F: %d\n", fCount);

    return 0;
}
```

This is an example program in a book i'm currently reading to count letter grades . So with this program I expect it that i can input all the grades in a line and end with the EOF (ctrl+Z) and then enter (eg: acffbcd). However the result is the default case in switch occur.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCR9b.png)

I know that the while loop will execute until getchar reach EOF, therefore it will never read the newline character, so the default case should not happen.
I change conditon in while loop into this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg9ig.png) to enter 1 to end the input instead of EOF and it works perfectly as I want.

So what exactly is the problem here? I will be really grateful for your help.

Comment: The first thing to do is print the value of `grade` when the default case is executed, to see what you're dealing with.  You can print it in hex, e.g. `printf("grade: %x\n", (unsigned) grade);`  You may be picking up a newline character from the end of the line, but you won't know until you look.

Comment: `ctrl-z` must be on a line by itself. So your input needs to be `abcd<enter>ctrl-z<enter>`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why the ctrl z should be on a line by itself, and do input like that also cause the default case to happen as the getchar read the newline character. Thanks for your help

Comment: Because that's the way Windows works. You'll need to add a case for the newline character and ignore it.

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried to make a case for \n with break; immediately after that and default case still happen. So the newline may be not the reason .

Comment: You could also be picking up a carriage return character.  This is OS-specific, so unless you tell us, we can only guess.

Comment: @TomKarzes It show 1a in the default case

Comment: `0x1a` is `ctrl-z` when not on a line by itself.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, ok, well that must be it then.  It's a raw ^Z character, resulting from it not being on its own line.  It's probably followed by a newline character.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that can explain the issue as I press ctrl+Z again in the newline, it exit the loop.

Comment: @Corvus Right, so basically, don't try to use ^Z for EOF unless it's the only thing on the line.

Comment: @TomKarzes I’m new to programming and also stackoverflow so I’m so sorry to let you frustrating like that. Thanks for your helps

Comment: The extra fun thing is that `abcd^z<enter>` never generates the newline character as far as `getchar` knows even though the cursor moves to the next line.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Huh, that's really weird.  Arguably a bug, but with Windows, who's counting?

Comment: @TomKarzes It probably isn't actually a bug, just a quirk based on the legacy of doing things the way CP/M did them way back in the day and being unable to change things because it would break backward compatibility.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Well, if that's the case then I'd view it as a "legacy bug that must be preserved for backward compatibility".

Comment: @TomKarzes We call those Load Bearing Bugs in our products. :)

Comment: Add and `int nCount = 0;` and a  `case '\n':  ++nCount; break;` in your `switch` and print the value of `nCount` at the end....

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF ){
    switch (grade){
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
```

To ignore whitespace chars. Not just '\n'. Whitespace chars include spaces, tabs, reverse tabs, carriage returns, end of line, and form feed chars.

```
while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF ){
    if (grade == ' ' || grade == '\t' || grade == '\v' || grade == '\r' || grade == '\f' || grade == '\n') {
        continue; // ignore whitespace
    }
    switch (grade){
        case 'A':
```

Of simply:

```
while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF ){
    if (isspace(grade)) {
        continue;
    }
    switch (grade){
        case 'A':
```

The isspace function, if not immediately available, can be added to your program by putting a `#include <ctype.h>` at the top of your code file.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int grade;
    int aCount = 0;
    int bCount = 0;
    int cCount = 0;
    int dCount = 0;
    int fCount = 0;

    printf("Enter grades\n");
    
// you have to change the EOF to '\n'
    while ((grade = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        switch (grade)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            ++aCount;
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            ++bCount;
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            ++cCount;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            ++dCount;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            ++fCount;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid\n");
            printf("Enter a new grade\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotals for each letter are:\n");
    printf("A: %d\n", aCount);
    printf("B: %d\n", bCount);
    printf("C: %d\n", cCount);
    printf("D: %d\n", dCount);
    printf("F: %d\n", fCount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't that make the program exit after reading in the first line?

Comment: No. this code this working correctly

Comment: Sure... It's working correctly by your definition. :) That is, your definition of how the program is to work is that the user is not expected to type any whitespace characters between letter grades and to press Enter when done. If that's your interpretation of the spec, then your code works perfectly.